# Why my ip is getting disappeared?

Tags: networking

I can connect to the internet. That was not my problem. I'm setting my ip and if I go back to view my ip in IPV4 properties of my Wi-Fi properties, I couldn't see it.But if I type ipconfig in command prompt, I'm getting the correct ip. I don't understand the reason why it was happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26667/discussion-on-question-by-user478451-why-my-ip-is-getting-disappeared).

Answer (score 2):

You can't see your IP address from the *'Wi-Fi properties'* if you are receiving an automatic IP address from DHCP. You can only see your IP address from *'Wi-Fi properties'* if you have assigned a static IP. Basically there's nothing to worry about.

Once you tick/check **Use the following IP address** then you can manually select the IP you want. In this case it's `192.168.0.144`.

[image: IP]

Once you tick/check **Obtain an IP address automatically** then the IP Address section grey's out and you can no longer see an IP Address.

[image: Auto]

To see your IP Address use IPCONFIG.